# Add layers to a pretrained model wihout creating a sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, pre-trained-model

I am using a pretrained Resnet50 (from the tensorflow.keras.applications package) and finetune it for multilabel classification (with 2 classes), and I'd like to extract the Saliency maps from the finetuned model.

To make a classifier, i add 2 dense layers to the Resnet model, creating a new sequential model as follow :

```
    self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        resnet50,
        layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='hidden_layer'),
        layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='output')
    ])
```

but my problem is that the resnet50 becomes a "single layer", like each layer is no more accessible : the model summary only contains 3 layers. I'd like to know if there is a way to add layers to a functional model without creating a sequential model, in order to be able to access each layer of the resnet model.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: ResNet is not a sequential model (due to the skip connections), so doing what you want does not make sense, and it is not needed as you can still access the layers inside the resnet (like resnet50.layers).

Answer (score 0):

To access layers of the resnet50 model, you have to first access the resnet50 layer aand then from that access the convolution layer for which you want to create saliency map.

```
self.model.get_layer("resnet50").get_layer("conv5_block2_3_conv")
```